# Materials malfunctioning after extrusion of mesh

Tags: mesh, materials, vertices, extrude

I am making a small speedometer/gauges box and have **extruded** a smaller rectangular prism on the side. As seen in picture 1 and 2 the material is distorted and a black area appears. The outer box has only the **'Box Metal'** material applied to it.

[image: Distorted material after extrusion.]

[image: Black missing material after extruding the rectangular prism.]

Comment: Probably inverted normals. Select All in Edit mode then Shift-N to recalculate the normals.

Comment: Tried this and it only fixed the black area. The lighting or material is still distorted on the side.

Comment: We'd need to see the Blend file in that case.  https://blend-exchange.com/help . If you have external materials don't forget to pack them into the Blend file before uploading. File > External data > Pack Resources.

Comment: That's alright. I'm remodeling the mesh anyway due to the simplicity and it seems to be working fine :) Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Probably best. It's all good practice! :^)